# Tool to Generate Load using the Database Sample Data

Tags: apache, testing, benchmarking, apachebench

I wanted to generate a load on my web application to measure/test that how many requests my web app can handle. Currently I am using Apache Benchmark For POST request. The problem is Apache Benchmark only use static data which is in file. I want such a tool which takes a sample data from database and generate load using that data randomly or sequentially. Can anybody tell me which tool is available for that? And Can that tool be able to provide a benchmark report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Apache JMeter. It can get dynamic data from textfiles (e.g. a CSV export from your database).

It does have a learning curve though, but once you get the hang of it, it is quite powerful.